# Function inside onload function undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page with a javascript function inside the window.onload that is not being initialized ("undefined is not a function"), and I don't know why.

My code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function loadthis(e,pg) {
    ...
 }
 window.onload = function() {
    loadthis(88,frm);
 }   
</script>
```

In virtually all browsers, this works fine, but in some (default Android browser and Dolphin) I get the following when `onload` tries to execute `loadthis(88,frm)`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I tried defining a `myonload()` function and calling it from the `body` tag, with the same behavior.

The page with the complete js code inside [is this](http://luis.impa.br).

**EDIT #1** It seems there are several inconsistencies in the JS engine of the browsers. For example, this code:

```
console.log("  ############## 1 ");
console.log("  ############## 2 "+frame);
console.log("  ############## 3 "+frame.src);
console.log("  ############## 4 "+frame.src.endsWith(pg));
```

gives this output:

```
############## 1 
############## 2 [object HTMLIFrameElement]
############## 3 http://luis.impa.br/varios/framebackground.html
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
```

No idea what this means. `frame.src` is defined. It seems the `.endsWith` simply does not work in these browsers.

**EDIT2**: For the record, this is the body of `loadthis`:

```
function loadthis(e,pg) { //{{{2
 clickbackground.trigger('click');
 jQuery("body").trigger("click");
 $('html').trigger('click');

 var evt = e || window.event;
 if (evt != 88 && evt !== "null") evt.preventDefault();
 if (evt.button == 1) {
   window.open(pg, '_blank');
 } else {
   //if (frame && frame.src && frame.src.endsWith(pg)) return;
   if (frame && frame.src && frame.src.match(pg) != null) return;
   if (evt !== 88) spinner.style.display = "block";
   if (frame && frame.src) {
    $.when($(frame).fadeOut(250)).promise().done(function() {
      //Comment for Dolphin
     frame.remove();
     frame.src = pg;
      //Comment for Dolphin
     container.append(frame);
     $(frame).fadeIn(600);
     });
   } else {
    if (!frame) frame = document.getElementById("MainFrame");
    $(frame).fadeOut(0);
    frame.src = pg;
    $(frame).fadeIn(600);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Not Sure where your error is throwing but ,i can see window.onload=buildflags,just change it as window.onload=function(){buildflags();}

Comment: @geeky: and whys that wrong??

Comment: @Geeky: tried your suggestion, but got the same problem.

Comment: Can you explain where exactly you have the issue...i tried to run the code ,i dont see any errors or any error message on console..If can you explain the scenario it would be great

Comment: @Geeky: I get no errors in Firefox and Chrome, both in Linux and Android. However, it does give errors in the default browser for Android (checked with USB debugging) and Dolphin, and the page does not work at all. I am sure this is a bug in both browsers, but I would like to rewrite my page for it to run under these browsers. In fact, the menu items call for the `loadthis` functions, and also do not work in these two browsers. Hope it is clearer now. I don't think there is something really wrong with my code, just want to overcome those browsers bugs.

Comment: What if you try window.onload = loadthis.bind(loadthis, 88, frm)

Comment: I got the error in 2 lines, in the `endWith`, and when tried to `container.append(frame)` after the `frame.remove()` since the browsers wrongly set the `frame` variable as undefined after the `remove()`. I have no question related to JQuery, and I have no further questions since I found how to overcome the browsers problems.

Comment: @K48: No, no luck.

Comment: @torazaburo: I wrote 3 times what happened and how I fixed the problem, in particular, in one of the answers. I don't know how to explain the solution better to you, sorry. Here it is again:  "Besides the lack of implementation of the `.endsWith()` function, the browsers sets as `undefined` the `frame` when I issued the `frame.remove()` command (I did this to prevent history on the iframe)." I will implement a different approach to get rid of the frame history.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the lack of implementation of the `.endsWith()` function, the browsers sets as `undefined` the `frame` when I issued the `frame.remove()` command (I did this to prevent history on the `iframe`).

Comment: @torazaburo: Sorry, didn't understand. I didn't raise a question here. Removed the last sentence, if that was what you meant.

Comment: @torazaburo: No, it is not a question, it is a claim.

Comment: @torazaburo: I already find out where the problem was.